# Explode feature doesn't seem to work on touch devices (Autodesk forge viewer)

Tags: touch, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When trying to use the slider that manages the explode feature with touch input nothing happens. When using the same slider in chrome with mouse input it works.

Behind the slider we find a `<input type="range">`. After some reading it seems that this html element works rather bad on touch input in general.

Even so much that there is a mini lib trying to improve range input on mobile.
https://rangetouch.com/ (which I might try out as a workaround)

Am I the only one with this problem or should this be addressed by autodesk?

Answer (score 0):

The Forge Viewer dev team is testing the features on various touch devices and they're working fine, incl. the explode tool (I've just confirmed that the tool works fine on an iPhone 6S), but it's possible that your HW/SW combination is not covered in those tests. Feel free to send your specifics to forge [dot] help [at] autodesk [dot] com, and we'll forward it to the developers.